# Weblogic 12c web service with http authentication

Tags: weblogic

We currently use a Weblogic client to talk to a WCF web service which is setup with a security mode of TranportWithMessageCredential.  This allows us to authenticate over HTTPS using username/password sent as part of the HTTP bindings.

We're now trying to do the reverse -- WCF client talking to a Weblogic 12c web service, with the same authentication scheme.  I think we have the client under control.

But how does one set up a Weblogic server is this fashion?